# Change text of DIV where Title equals

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am looking to do something like this: (Wont work..)

```
<script>
$(document).ready(
    $('a[title="Girls"] .ellipsis_text').text('test');
);
```

To change the span text with the class ellipsis_text from the following code:

```
<li><a href="http://www.site.com/girls" title="Girls"><span class="cls_truncate_text"><span class='ellipsis_text'>Girls</span></span></a></li>
```

Do anybody know how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You forgot `function()`

Try with

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a[title="Girls"] .ellipsis_text').text('test');
});
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/M25sx/

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('a[title="Girls"]').find('.ellipsis_text').html('test');
});
```